# Setting Permission for Files in the network

Tags: networking

I need to set permission for a drive on a network where user can edit and update the file but the must not copy the files from the network drive to local system.

Comment: What Operating System, what kind of network protocol is this drive connected by?

Answer (score 1):

Ah! This is impossible, anyone who can edit and update files already has read permissions on the file, so he can surely copy it to his/her local machine. It can only be circumvented by using complex methods such as a web-based service.

Comment: Is there any other implementation to protect the files .

Comment: You might want to set up a small web server which runs code to get the data from the user and write it to the required file.